# Crop inserted image

Tags: graphics

I'm preparing figures for a paper. The following command gives me a figure like this:[image]
The question is I only need one colorbar. So the right colorbar should be delete.
I've tried to delete the colorbar of the right image in MATLAB. But it will give me an image larger than the left one. And it's difficult to make them same.

I was wondering whether there is a way to hide the colorbar of the right image just like the crop operator in word.

Thank you so much.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.33\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{uxfea.eps}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.33\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ux800cub04.eps}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Option `trim` together with `clip` help:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.33\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{uxfea.eps}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.33\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, trim=0 0 2cm 0, clip]{ux800cub04.eps}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The amount (the example uses `2cm`) depends on your figure.
The default unit for the values in `trim` is `bp`. The four values mean trimming from left, bottom, right, and top.

Comment: But the rectangle after trim would be larger than the left rectangle. How can I adjust this?

Comment: Thank you so much! I decrease the width of the second subfigure after using trim. Now they look the same. @Heiko Oberdiek

Comment: @Windy The width of the image can be derived from the `%%BoundingBox` comment in the EPS file (unit is bp). Then the correct parameters for the `subfigure` width can be calculated to get the same scaling factors. Also an option is using `scale` instead of `width` in `\includegraphics` to set and get the same scaling factor.